# Error Number: 1364 Field 'modified_at' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

when i try to make stricton value to **TRUE** then it shows error `Error Number: 1364  Field 'modified_at' doesn't have a default value"` and when try to make it **FALSE** then it shows error

```
Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @@sql_mode'
SELECT GET_LOCK('ad3549572403a9c71bea1109d26f4b48', 300) AS ci_session_lock
```

when the value is true, everything is working but i need to refresh to make error: "Error Number: 1364  Field 'modified_at' doesn't have a default value" gone.
please help me to overcome this fault.
thank uu!

Here is the screenshot of the errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CHKI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VICiT.png)

Answer (score 3):

Make this column nullable.Beacuse here modified_at is not nullable.When you a save a row data you passed every element but you didn't save any data into modified_at. so make this column nullable.

```
$table->date('modified_at')->nullable();
```

If you haven't enough data then

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

If you have enough data on database & don't wabt to refresh it then add a new migration file. & make this column nullable.like

```
Schema::table('your_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('modified_at')->nullable()->change();
});
```

For details
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the value to 'modified_at' column when inserting the data so the error is thrown.

You should either make that column have a default value or seeing the column name I guess making it nullable will do.

*(Assuming the column is a date field and using Laravel)*

You will have to use [Column modifier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers) `->nullable()`

Migration:

```
$table->date('modified_at')->nullable();
```

.